# How to change UICollectionView frame on button touch

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uicollectionview, cgrect

I am trying following **code** but nothing works :

```
CGRect frame  = collectionview.frame;  
collectionview.frame = CGRectMake (frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y+100, frame.size, frame.size-100);
```

AutoLayout is set to true for the project.

Comment: are you reload collectionview after change its frame ?

Comment: maybe your collection view has constrains

Comment: Yes Rushabh. I reload Collection View.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
CGRect frame  = collectionview.frame;  
collectionview.frame = CGRectMake (frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y+100, frame.size.width, frame.size.height-100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
CGRect frame = collectionview.frame;
frame = CGRectMake (frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y+100, frame.size, frame.size-100);
collectionview.frame=frame;
```